# Looping for splitting the given string in mysql

Tags: mysql

I tried this code manually. How can I put this code on loop in mysql. Here is the `Delimit('#'==-2)` constant

```
Set @x1=                                                                                                                      '@@863071010318301,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318302,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0900,#
             @@863071010318303,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318304,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318305,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318306,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318307,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318308,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318309,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318310,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#';

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@x1,'@@',8),'#',-2)
```

Comment: Do you want to have as much rows as values separated by the delimiter `,#` and have a length > 0?

Comment: yes each and every should contain                                              @@863071010318306,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#                                                            this type data...,how can put into loop & how to splitting the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the parts as rows with following statements:

```
Set @x1=    '@@863071010318301,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318302,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0900,#
             @@863071010318303,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318304,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318305,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318306,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318307,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318308,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318309,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#
             @@863071010318310,201526,1100.7812,N,07657.7134,E,0.00,060814,A,0,1,0,1,1,0,0799,0800,#';

-- we set the separator strings that mark the begin and the end of the part we want:
SET @pre = '@@';
SET @post = ',#';

SELECT CONCAT(@pre, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@x1, @post, t.n), @pre, -1), @post) FROM (SELECT @x1 as haystack) h
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
        1 + a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 AS n
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
    ORDER BY n
) t
WHERE t.n <=
(
    (
        LENGTH(@x1) 
        - 
        LENGTH(REPLACE(@x1, @post, ''))
    ) 
    / LENGTH(@post)
);
```

## Explanation

**First step: setting of markers:**

We set the separator strings that mark the begin and the end of the part we want:

```
SET @pre = '@@';
SET @post = ',#';
```

**Second step: getting the needed part**

We use an expression similar to yours to get the part we want to have. Because our @pre and @post separators belong to the part we want and SUBSTRING_INDEX eliminates them, we've got to concatenate them afterwards again.

```
SELECT CONCAT(@pre, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@x1, @post, t.n), @pre, -1), @post) 
FROM (SELECT @x1 as haystack) h
```

** Third step: generating numbers**

The trick to fill the part number, here `t.n` with numbers is to do a cross join with a number generating query:

```
SELECT 
    1 + a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 AS n
FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
    ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
ORDER BY n
```

This kind of query is easily adaptable to get as many numbers as one wants.

**Last step: limiting the numbers as needed**

```
WHERE t.n <=
(
    (
        LENGTH(@x1) 
        - 
        LENGTH(REPLACE(@x1, @post, ''))
    ) 
    / LENGTH(@post)
);
```

- Get the difference in string length by replacing the separator by an empty string
- Divide the result by the length of the separator

You can have a look at [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe644/1)

Comment: i create one temporary table for maintaining the recent entry of 200 records.

       SET @x1=SELECT * FROM tbl_temp ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 200;
       DELETE FROM tbl_temp WHERE Id NOT IN (@x1)

but it does not work properly..plz help me

Comment: That's another question, but what did work for me was following query: `DELETE FROM tbl_temp WHERE id < (SELECT(MIN(t.id) FROM (SELECT id FROM tbl_temp ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 200) t);`

Comment: this is not working..,if my temp exceeds 400 records..,i want to delete 200 records..,at the same time i want to maintain the 200 recent records in the same table..

Comment: There was one parenthese too many: `DELETE FROM tbl_temp WHERE id < (SELECT MIN(t.id) FROM (SELECT id FROM tbl_temp ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 200) t);`

Comment: can you execute on sqlfiddle

Comment: In my [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5947d/1) you see it with a table with 8 rows. I delete all but the most recent 2.

Comment: 'SET @x1=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_temp;
IF @x1>10 THEN DO
DELETE FROM tbl_temp WHERE Id < (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM (SELECT Id FROM tbl_temp ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 8)t);
ELSE
END IF;'

Comment: DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    
    PROCEDURE `trackdata`.`proc_temp`()
    
    BEGIN
    SET @x1=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_temp;
IF @x1>10 THEN 
DELETE FROM tbl_temp WHERE Id < (
SELECT MIN(Id) 
FROM 
(SELECT Id FROM tbl_temp ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 8)
);
END IF;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;